# duplicate values when using inner join on array columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have an `appointment` table in which two of the fields, `pets` and `services` are arrays. I'm trying to craft a query that lists the `starts_at` and `ends_at` time in addition to the names of the services and pets associated with that appointment.

The issue I'm running into is that if either `pets` or `services` contains more than 1 value, I run into duplicate values in my output.

Here's the query I currently have:

```
SELECT
    appointment.starts_at,
    appointment.ends_at,
    string_agg(service.name, ', ') AS service_names,
    string_agg(pet.name, ', ') AS pet_names
FROM get_appointments(20, CURRENT_DATE, CAST((CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL '1 day' * 4) AS DATE), null, null) AS appointment
INNER JOIN pet on pet.id = ANY(appointment.pets)
INNER JOIN service on service.id = ANY(appointment.services)
GROUP BY
    appointment.starts_at,
    appointment.ends_at
ORDER BY
    appointment.starts_at ASC;
```

Here's sample output:

```
+---------------------+---------------------+--------------------------------+-------------------+
|      starts_at      |       ends_at       |         service_names          |     pet_names     |
+---------------------+---------------------+--------------------------------+-------------------+
| 2017-05-03 07:00:00 | 2017-05-03 07:30:00 | 30 Minute Walk, 30 Minute Walk | Gregor, The Hound |
+---------------------+---------------------+--------------------------------+-------------------+
```

Here's the desired output:

```
+---------------------+---------------------+--------------------------------+-------------------+
|      starts_at      |       ends_at       |         service_names          |     pet_names     |
+---------------------+---------------------+--------------------------------+-------------------+
| 2017-05-03 07:00:00 | 2017-05-03 07:30:00 | 30 Minute Walk          | Gregor, The Hound |
+---------------------+---------------------+--------------------------------+-------------------+
```

I'm running Postgres 9.5.

Thank you!

Comment: The simplest way is `string_agg(distinct service.name, ', ')`, but IMO you should to rethink your query...

Comment: Thank you. If you're recommending I consider  a different approach, do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe some people are smarter than me, but what is `FROM get_appointments(20, ...` ? a function, I presume?

Comment: @wildplasser correct!

Comment: @jdixon04 See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
    appointment.starts_at,
    appointment.ends_at,
    (select string_agg(service.name, ', ') from service where service.id = ANY(appointment.services)) AS service_names,
    (select string_agg(pet.name, ', ') from pet where pet.id = ANY(appointment.pets)) AS pet_names
FROM get_appointments(20, CURRENT_DATE, CAST((CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL '1 day' * 4) AS DATE), null, null) AS appointment
GROUP BY
    appointment.starts_at,
    appointment.ends_at
ORDER BY
    appointment.starts_at ASC;
```

And same using [lateral joins](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-LATERAL):

```
SELECT
    appointment.starts_at,
    appointment.ends_at,
    service_names,
    pet_names
FROM get_appointments(20, CURRENT_DATE, CAST((CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL '1 day' * 4) AS DATE), null, null) AS appointment
  cross join lateral (
    select string_agg(service.name, ', ')  AS service_names
    from service
    where service.id = ANY(appointment.services)) as srv
  cross join lateral (
    select string_agg(pet.name, ', ')  AS pet_names
    from pet
    where pet.id = ANY(appointment.pets)) as pet
GROUP BY
    appointment.starts_at,
    appointment.ends_at
ORDER BY
    appointment.starts_at ASC;
```